# How do I create a global high score for my android app?

Tags: android

I have finished and released my game and it contains a local highscore list for each phone. I would like to make it so that the scores are global..ie. send score to a server and server sends the highest scores to all the phones when they connect

Unfortunately I have no idea where to begin. So if somebody could point out a link or give me an explanation on how to proceed I'd be very appreciative, thanks!

Comment: rather then implement this yourself you should consider using OpenFeint or another social gaming API. It will be many times simpler and cheaper than trying to run your own server.

Answer (score 9):

You have the general idea. You have to:

- Send the score to a server
- Retrieve the high score table from the server

This means that you probably want to have some sort of web-based API for these two. The easiest way is to simply let someone else do it. There are free services out there that already provide global high scores. There are probably more, but for Android, [OpenFeint](http://openfeint.com/) and [ScoreLoop](http://www.scoreloop.com/) are two big ones that I know of. You can look through their docs and see if you want to use them.

Alternatively, you can roll your own. This is a bit more work (though honestly not all **that** hard). If you go this route I'd recommend you build a web service that you can post scores to. The web service would save the score to a database and then when the client calls the web service to retrieve scores, the web service queries the score database and returns them.

That's a general outline, because frankly how to build that web service is a whole other question, and you'd have to decide on a language/platform etc. for that too.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Looks like I either have a lot of studying to do or...does anybody know a similar service for blackberry?

Comment: I just looked and apparently ScoreLoop was just acquired by RIM! They should have excellent Blackberry support now (or soon)...

Comment: OpenFeint was acquired and dissolved some time ago.
ScoreLoop was acquired by RIM, now BlackBerry, and will close down on December 2014.

Comment: Facebook has a basic score system for apps. They only allow 1 score per user, and can only compete with friends by default but it's easy to use and good for boosting presence.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Swarm's Leaderboard](http://swarmconnect.com/leaderboards) system, which is similar to the others mentioned here (ScoreLoop/OpenFeint), just another alternative to consider :)

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at Scoreloop 1.0 in NDK 2.0 release for BB. 
https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/native/beta/?CPID=TWDToolDL&Date=112311